# Maximize $\sum_{i=1}^N \log\left( 1+a_i b_i c_i \right)$ under $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i \to \infty$ and $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i \to 0$

Tags: optimization, summation, logarithms, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have a log-sum maximization problem of the form:
$$
\max_{\left\{ a_i \right\},\left\{ b_i \right\},\left\{ c_i \right\}} ~ \sum_{i=1}^N \log\left(1+ a_i b_i c_i \right)
$$
subject to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N a_i =A, ~ \sum_{i=1}^N b_i =B, ~ \textrm{and}~ \sum_{i=1}^N c_i =C,
$$
$A$, $B$, and $C$ are both positive numbers. I want to know the solutions to such a problem when $A\to \infty$ and $A\to 0$. I believe that when $A\to \infty$, the solution should be
$$
a_i=\frac{A}{N},~ b_i=\frac{B}{N},~ \textrm{and}~ c_i=\frac{C}{N},~ \textrm{for all}~ i\in \left\{1,\ldots,N\right\},
$$
and when $A\to 0$, the solution should be
$$
a_i=A,~ b_i=B,~ \textrm{and}~ c_i=C,~\textrm{for}~ i=1 \\
a_i=0,~ b_i=0,~ \textrm{and}~ c_i=0,~ \textrm{for}~ i\in \left\{2,\ldots,N\right\},
$$
or concentrate $A$, $B$, and $C$ on another $i\neq 1$. Am I right? If so, how to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

Using Lagrange multipliers, we know that at an extremum $(a_1,\dots,a_N,b_1\dots,b_N,c_1,\dots,c_N)$,
$$\left\{
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial a_i}(a_1,\dots,a_N,b_1\dots,b_N,c_1,\dots,c_N) &= \frac{b_ic_i}{1+a_ib_ic_i}&=\lambda\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial b_i}(a_1,\dots,a_N,b_1\dots,b_N,c_1,\dots,c_N) &= \frac{a_ic_i}{1+a_ib_ic_i}&=\mu\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial c_i}(a_1,\dots,a_N,b_1\dots,b_N,c_1,\dots,c_N) &= \frac{a_ib_i}{1+a_ib_ic_i}&=\gamma\\
\end{split}\right.$$
where $f$ is the function to optimize, and noting that the partial derivatives of the constraints are all equal to $1$.

This means that for all $i$'s,
$$\lambda a_i=\mu b_i = \gamma c_i$$
Summing over all $i$'s:
$$\lambda A = \mu B = \gamma C$$
and thus for all $i$'s
$$
\frac{b_ic_i}{1+a_ib_ic_i}=\frac{BCa_i^2}{A^2+BCa_i^3}=\lambda
$$
Consequently,
$$\frac{BCa_i^2}{A^2+BCa_i^3}=\frac{BCa_i^2}{A^2+BCa_2^3}=\dots=\frac{BCa_N^2}{A^2+BCa_N^3}=\lambda \tag{2}$$
By studying $x\mapsto \frac{BCx^2}{A^2+BCx^3}$, you can see that this function reaches $\lambda$ either $0$ time or $2$ times on $(0,+\infty)$.
But to maximize the original function, we need to take $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_N$ such that they are the maximum value such that $(2)$ is satisfied.

In conclusion,
$$\boxed{
a_i=\frac A N \text{, }
b_i=\frac B N \text{, }
c_i=\frac C N}$$
Note: This doesn't depend on the specific value of $A$.

Comment: Thank you Lafon but does it really independent of the value of $A$? I have chosen some specific values to check. Let $A=0.01$ (to approximate $A\to 0$), $B=1$, $C=1$, and $N=2$. For $a_1=a_2=0.005$, $b_1=b_2=0.5$, and $c_1=c_2=0.5$, the objective funcion equals $2*\log(1+0.005*0.5*0.5)=0.0025$ (Natural logarithm). But for $a_1=0.01$, $b_1=1$, $c_1=1$, and $a_2=b_2=c_2=0$, the objective function equals $\log(1+0.01)=0.01$. So is there something wrong?